# App Store app needs to be re-signed with Apple's latest code signing certificate

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, code-signing, apple-developer

Today I received an email from Apple in regards to an iOS app:

> #### Courtesy notice about your app.
>
> from: Apple Developer developer@email.apple.com
>
> Hello NAME,
>
> We noticed that your app, APP_NAME, hasn’t been updated since 2018_DATE and continues to use a legacy App Store code signing certificate. As a result, your app needs to be re-signed with our latest code signing certificate, which will be required for apps to launch in upcoming releases of iOS 14.5 and iPadOS 14.5.
>
> We plan to update your app on the App Store soon with the latest code signature and your product page’s What’s New text with “This app has been updated by Apple to use the latest Apple signing certificate.”
>
> No action is required.
>
> If you have any questions, [contact us](https://developer.apple.com/contact/).
>
> Best regards,
> Apple Developer Relations

What "legacy App Store code signing certificate" is this in reference to? What are the details of this required signing certificate update?

What changes does Apple want to make to the app?

Will the shipping Version Number or Build Number change? Will customers be prompted to download a new version of the app?

Can I instead make this update myself?

Comment: https://www.macrumors.com/2021/04/16/psa-apple-updating-old-apps-latest-certificate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update has now occurred for my app.

The version number remains the same. The last app update date still says "X years ago".

The "What's New" text of the app update field has been prepended with the text:

> This app has been updated by Apple to use the latest Apple signing certificate.

The previous app update text is then listed below that new note from Apple.

Comments in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/mrkbm4/this_app_has_been_updated_by_apple_to_use_the/) seem to indicate that such apps *were* updated on iOS devices, and appeared up in the "Updates" tab of the App Store.